# Quick way to store and retrieve cell details - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner. For my VBA project, in my 8th row I have 40+ columns that have contents. I want to check whether the cells contains required content, if yes I want to store that cell column position in a variable.

Currently I am using for loop to accomplish this. My query is, is there any way to do this quickly and store the column values in a array and retrieve it later.

The code I used here is,

```
rowposition =8

lastcol = ws1.Cells(8, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For findval = 1 To lastcol

If ws1.Cells(rowposition, findval).Value = "Sl.No" Then
    slno = ws1.Cells(rowposition, findval).Column
    ws1.Range("CQ9:CQ9").Value = slno
    
    ElseIf ws1.Cells(rowposition, findval).Value = "PIF No." Then
    pif = ws1.Cells(rowposition, findval).Column
    ws1.Range("CE9:CE9").Value = pif
    
    ElseIf ws1.Cells(rowposition, findval).Value = "Vertical" Then
    verticals = ws1.Cells(rowposition, findval).Column
    ws1.Range("CM9:CM9").Value = verticals
.
.
.
.
.so on......

If slno =Empty or pif = Empty Or verical= Empty Or Then

MsgBox ("Columns have been modified please check")

exit sub

End If
```

Comment: It is unclear what *cell column position* and *single array* mean. Does it e.g. mean that you have a list of strings e.g. `aList = "Sl.No,PIF No.,Vertical"` and if they are found in columns `F,C,A` you want to return `6,3,1` in an array? Also the rows are a bit confusing: in the text you use row `8`, while in the code you use `7` (for calculating the last column) and `9` (for the 'search'). Please do clarify.

Comment: sorry for not being clear. The contents are found in row 8 and in columns A,B,C etc. If the conditions are met the column position should be stored in an array and retrieved for later use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Positions of the Values of One Array in Another

- The values for the test are `PIF No.,Vertical,Sl.No` in the range `A8:C8`. `Test` is a value not found.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub writePositions()

    ' Initial is a 1D zero-based array.
    ' Current is a 2D one-based (one-row) array.
    ' Positions is a 1D one-based array.

    ' Define constants.        
    Const HeaderRow As Long = 8
    Const FirstCol As Long = 1
    ' Define Initial Header Array.
    Dim Initial As Variant
    ' VBA.Array is ensuring 0-based.
    Initial = VBA.Array("Sl.No", "Test", "PIF No.", "Vertical") ' add more.
    
    ' Define worksheet.
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ' Define Last Column in header row.
    Dim LastCol As Long
    LastCol = ws1.Cells(HeaderRow, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ' Define Current Header Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws1.Cells(HeaderRow, FirstCol).Resize(1, LastCol - FirstCol + 1)
    ' Write values from Current Header Range to Current Header Array.
    Dim Current As Variant
    Current = rng.Value
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim Positions As Variant
    Dim j As Long
    
    ' Write the positions of the values of Initial Header Array
    ' found in Current Header Array, to Positions Array.
    ' Note that Positions will contain error values for all the values
    ' of Initial not found in Current.
    Positions = Application.Match(Initial, Current, 0)
    
    ' View the results in the Immediate window (VBE: CRTL+G):
    Debug.Print "Initial:"
    Debug.Print "Index", "Initial", "Position in Current"
    For j = 0 To UBound(Initial)
        If IsNumeric(Positions(j + 1)) Then
            Debug.Print j + 1, Initial(j), Positions(j + 1)
        Else
            Debug.Print j + 1, Initial(j), "Not found"
        End If
    Next j

    ' The other way around.
    
    ' Write the positions of the values of Current Header Array
    ' found in Initial Header Array, to Positions Array.
    ' Note that Positions will contain error values for all the values
    ' of Current not found in Initial.
    Positions = Application.Match(Current, Initial, 0)
    
    ' View the results in the Immediate window (VBE: CRTL+G):
    Debug.Print "Current:"
    Debug.Print "Index", "Current", "Position in Initial"
    For j = 1 To UBound(Current, 2)
        If IsNumeric(Positions(j)) Then
            Debug.Print j, Current(1, j), Positions(j)
        Else
            Debug.Print j, Current(1, j), "Not found"
        End If
    Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that I have made a correction: `ws1.Columns.Count` instead of `Columns.Count`.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide solution to this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/q/66021845/14361287

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know anything about `Outlook`, yet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am tiring to trigger email notification to a remote server/computer on saving the excel file. So far no useful leads, that's why asked you

Answer (score 0):

You should read the whole sheet into an array and loop through that. It will be a magnitude faster. (Carful, that array will start at index 1 - use LBound To UBound to iterate it)

```
Dim sheetArray As Variant
sheetArray = ws.UsedRange()
```

you can just store the value of findval for when you found a value.

```
If sheetArray(rowposition, findval)= "Sl.No" Then
    slno = findval
    ws1.Range("CQ9:CQ9").Value = slno
```